# is there an alternitive to display: grid that is supported for gmail and/or outlook?

Tags: html, css, gmail, css-grid, html-email

was pretty proud of myself that I managed to make the custom grid I wanted for a client but then I was told it needs to work for email too. tried looking at different alternatives for display: grid on the web but couldn't find any.

does such an alternative exist? and suggestions if not?

for reference here is the grid I made:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(30px, auto);
  
  
}
.one {
  grid-column: 1 / 16;
  grid-row: 1 / 9;
  background-color: black;
}
.two {
  grid-column: 16 / 21;
  grid-row: 1 / 9;
  background-color: red;
}
.three {
  grid-column: 1/7;
  grid-row: 9 / 12;
  background-color: green;
}
.four {
  grid-column: 15/21;
  grid-row: 9/12;
  background-color: blue;
}
.five {
  grid-column: 1/11;
  grid-row: 12/17;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.six {
  grid-column: 11/21;
  grid-row: 12/17;
  background-color: purple;
}
.seven {
  grid-column: 7/15;
  grid-row: 9/12;
  background-color: gray;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
  <div class="five">Five</div>
  <div class="six">Six</div>
  <div class="seven">text</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The support for `CSS` or `Head-Style` is quite poor for E-Mails with ~45%
[citatation: CSS support](https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=css)

So overall you should relay on `inline-style` when designing an email-template.

Neither `CSS-Grid` (~59% supported) nor `Flexbox` (~59% supported) have a reasonable support from email clients.
[citatation: CSS-Grid support](https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=grid)
[citatation: Flexbox support](https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=flexbox)

The only thing you can do is to use a `<table>` which has a solid 100% support as it is a HTML solution. It is not tabular data but for email-templates acceptable as it is the only method that is fully supported!
[citatation: table support](https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=table)

**Email-Template:**

As said above, we have to use a table. The equivalent to the `grid-gap` would be the combination of `border-collapse: seperate;` + `border-spacing: value;` directly used on the table itself: `<table style="border-collapse: seperate; border-spacing: 10px;">`

To emulate your `grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 1fr);` I started with an empty `<tr>` that has 20x `<td width="5%">`

this now allows us to use the `colspan`-attribute to span multiple columns just like `grid-column: spanX`

to emulate the min-height you just have to apply the `height`-attribute which is the same as `min-height` for tables as a tablecell will resize if the content is larger. I simply tooked your 30px times the rows you wanted to span.

To have the text start in the top left corner instead of the center of the table cell you have to apply: `text-align:left; vertical-align:top;` to every single `<td>`.

```html
<table width="100%;" style="border-collapse: seperate; border-spacing: 10px;">
  <tr>
    <td width="5%;"></td>
    <td width="5%;"></td>
    <td width="5%;"></td>
    <td width="5%;"></td>
    <td width="5%;"></td>
    <td width="5%;"></td>
    <td width="5%;"></td>
    <td width="5%;"></td>
    <td width="5%;"></td>
    <td width="5%;"></td>
    <td width="5%;"></td>
    <td width="5%;"></td>
    <td width="5%;"></td>
    <td width="5%;"></td>
    <td width="5%;"></td>
    <td width="5%;"></td>
    <td width="5%;"></td>
    <td width="5%;"></td>
    <td width="5%;"></td>
    <td width="5%;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="240px">
    <td colspan="15" style="background-color:black; color:white; text-align:left; vertical-align:top;">one</td>
    <td colspan="5" style="background-color:red; text-align:left; vertical-align:top;">two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="90px">
    <td colspan="6" style="background-color:green; text-align:left; vertical-align:top;">three</td>
    <td colspan="8" style="background-color:gray; text-align:left; vertical-align:top;">text</td>
    <td colspan="6" style="background-color:blue; text-align:left; vertical-align:top;">four</td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="150px">
    <td colspan="10" style="background-color:yellow; text-align:left; vertical-align:top;">five</td>
    <td colspan="10" style="background-color:purple; text-align:left; vertical-align:top;">six</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's a great equivalent--but take note how it looks on mobiles. There may not be enough room once it gets squished down: https://litmus.com/checklist/emails/public/ded6145

Comment: @Nathan yes but then same rule applies to a true grid and thats what you normally have media queries for. That an email-template should be minimalistic for that exact reason is conceptional. As such it would fit for a review site but not for the actual question that was asked.